# Qual è il significato di "referto" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro *I migliori anni della nostra vita* di Ernesto Ferrero ho letto:

> Ma come riuscire a dire qualcosa di sensato su un volume che raccontava i prodigi della nuova musica elettronica, se perfino il musicologo ufficiale della casa, Massimo Mila, aveva rifiutato di scriverne con una smorfia d'insofferenza? Che cosa scrivere dei noiosissimi romanzi-**referto** di Robbe-Grillet e degli altri agrimensori francesi dell'École du regard?

Ho cercato il vocabolo "referto" in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capire il suo significato in questo contesto. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Un *referto*, in vari ambiti, è una relazione ufficiale, in genere redatta da un medico o dall'arbitro di una gara, che quindi in genere non si distingue per cura delle stile e per valore letterario. E all'arida prosa di un referto somigliano evidentemente, secondo Ferrero, i romanzi di Alain Robbe-Grillet e degli altri “agrimensori” (e quindi non veri scrittori, secondo lui, ma più simili a tecnici) suoi connazionali.